# Exclude one directory from Nginx password authentication

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, debian-based

I have setup my Nginx server to have authentication for everything, but I want to exclude all the files under `/var/www/html/t/sms/plivo` for password authentication. I have tried using different paths but it always asks for a password when I try to access a file under `/var/www/html/t/sms/plivo` from my browser.

Below is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        auth_basic "Private Property";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        #no password for the plivo folder so we can recieve messages!
        location = /t/sms/plivo/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all; # Allow all to see content
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `location =` syntax matches one URI and not all of the URIs under it. Also, you should use the `^~` modifier to prevent the regular expression `location` blocks from interfering. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for the rules regarding the evaluation order for `location` blocks.

If you have any PHP files under `/t/sms/plivo/` you will need to add a nested location block to handle those.

For example:

```
location ^~ /t/sms/plivo/ {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all; # Allow all to see content

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

That `location ~ \.php$` block is in addition to the block already in your configuration with the same name. And, you probably do not need the `allow all` statement, unless you have some `deny` rules that I cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

hope it will help anyone - we have to skip auth for ALL uri's under the url, so

```
location ^~ /some/location/to_skip/ {
  auth_basic off;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```